# How do I union integer set?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, union

I am having trouble with school assignment. I have no idea how to write a union method from passing only one integer set. How can I access two integer sets so I can merge them?

```java
//Test class
        IntegerSet set1 = new IntegerSet(array1);
        IntegerSet set2 = new IntegerSet(array1);
        System.out.println("set1: " + set1);
        System.out.println("set2: " + set2);

    



//Method I have to write in another class.
public IntegerSet union(IntegerSet otherSet) {
    return null;
}
```

Comment: One of the sets will be the object that's passed in.  The other will be the object that you call the method on.

Comment: Not sure what that means, can you please provide a code example or explain more? I'd appreciate it.

Comment: If you coded "another class" correctly, method `union (IntegerSet otherSet)` has access to an `IntegerSet` that is named `otherSet`. It also has access to an object of whatever type "another class" is. The name of that other object is `this`. Presumptions follow in next comment.

Comment: Presumably, method `union (IntegerSet otherSet)` is a method of class `IntegerSet`.  If so, that method will have access to two objects of type `IntegerSet`. One is named `otherSet`. The other is named `this`. You want that method to create a 3rd set -- a `new IntegerSet`, copy the elements from `this` and from `otherSet` into the new set. Presumably, you want to eliminate duplicates. Return the new set.

Comment: If an IntegerSet is actually a 'set', in the sense we usually understand it in programming, then it must not contain duplicates.